# Asp GridView select a row then fire event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Here is the scenario ..

I have a `GridView` with columns `ID`, `Name`, and `Type`. `Name` is click enabled and will redirect to other page. The entire row can be selected, and using `jQuery` I changed its background so it will be recognized as selected row.

The reason it must be selected is because a `link`, for example `Delete` is present at the page. When `Delete` is clicked, it should delete the selected row but when there is no selected row, it should do nothing.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server">Delete</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:GridView ID="gridView" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gridView_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="gridView_Command" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
    <columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lb1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' CommandName="NameButton" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" />
    </columns>
</asp:GridView>

public void gridView_Command(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "NameButton")
    {
        var id = e.CommandArgument;
        // redirect to edit page //
    }
}
```

I am using `jQuery` to indicate that a row is selected.

I already have the code for the `Delete` event method but my problem is how can I tell the compiler that a row is currently selected upon clicked of `Delete`?

I am thinking of using a `hidden field`, and on `jQuery`, I will set the value of the hidden field to the `ID` of the row that is selected. However, I still don't have the idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty straight. You can store the `SelectedIndex` in a hidden field and find the `GridViewRow` by the index.

Add a hidden field in the markup and also attach an event method to the Link button:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" runat="server">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnIndex" runat="server" />

<asp:GridView ID="gridView" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gridView_RowDataBound"
    OnRowCommand="gridView_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lb1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' CommandName="NameButton" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In the GridView RowDataBound add an attribute to execute javascript to save index in hidden field:

```
protected void gridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript: getElementById('" + hdnIndex.ClientID + "').value='" + e.Row.RowIndex + "';");
    }    
}
```

And `LinkButton`'s click event do like this:

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = 0;
    int id = 0;

    if (int.TryParse(hdnIndex.Value, out index))
    {
        GridViewRow gvr = gridView.Rows[index];
        if (gvr != null &&  int.TryParse(gvr.Cells[0].Text, out id) )
        {
            // id is available here
            // do wahtever you want  with the id
            // even you can delete the record from db by id
        }               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess command-argument is what you are searching for...**[Check this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**
 You just need to pass the `Id` using command argument from front-end to the code file and from there you can delete it easily.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. How will I pass the `Id`?